Maximizing Perimeter of Triangle PDE on a Parabola and Finding Coordinates of N for Rhombus Formation
Given a parabola in the Cartesian plane defined by the equation ( $y = -\frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{3}{2}x + 2 $), it intersects the x-axis at points A and B, and the y-axis at point C. Consider a point P on the parabola above line BC. A perpendicular line from P to BC meets at point D, and a line parallel to the y-axis through P intersects line BC at point E. It is known that the perimeter of triangle PDE is maximized at ( $\frac{6\sqrt{5}}{5} + 2$ ) when P is at ( $(2, 3)$ ).
The parabola is then translated along the ray CB by ( $\sqrt{5}$ ) units, placing point M on the axis of symmetry of the new parabola. We are to find all coordinates of point N such that the quadrilateral formed by points A, P, M, and N is a rhombus.
Key Points:

How can we calculate all possible positions for point N based on these conditions?

Attempt:
I calculated the intersection points of the parabola with the axes and found the coordinates for points A and B by solving the quadratic equation from the parabola's formula. I derived the perimeter condition for triangle PDE and established point P's position at ( $(2, 3)$ ).
For translating the parabola, I used the vector direction from point C to B to determine the translation vector. However, I need help understanding how to correctly apply the rhombus condition to find all possible coordinates for point N.
Question:
Can anyone provide insight or methods to determine the coordinates of point N such that APNM forms a rhombus? What are the necessary geometric or algebraic steps to resolve this part of the problem?



Diagonal AN must be perpendicular on diagonal MP. We need to find the coordinates of F, the mid point of MP and AN. We have:
$A(-1, 0)$, $B(4, 0)$, $C((0, 2)$, $P(2, 3)$
1-Equation of BC:$\frac {x-0}{4-0}=\frac{y-2}{0-2}\rightarrow y=-\frac12 x+2$
2- equation of PM: $m=-\frac12\rightarrow y-3=-\frac12 (x-2)\rightarrow y=-\frac 12 x +4$
3-Equation of AN:$m=\frac{-1}{-\frac 12}=2\rightarrow y=2x+2$
4-(2) with (3) give $F(\frac 45, \frac {18}5)$
5-$x_F=\frac{x_A+x_N}2\Rightarrow x_N=2x_F-x_A=2(\frac45)-(-1)=\frac {13}5$
6-$y_F=\frac{y_A+y_N}2\Rightarrow y_N=2y_F-y_A=2(\frac{18}5)-0=\frac {36}5$
$N(\frac{13}5, \frac{36}5)$
I think this is the only possible point.Note that $CE=\sqrt{2^2+1^2}=\sqrt 5$
The equation of new parabola is:
$-\frac1{1.04}y=(x-2.53)(x+3.33)$

Thank you for your answer."Note that we translate the original parabola along the ray CB."

@OthS, Ad must be perpendicular on PM, I think this is possible if the translation is along BC. If it must along CB then there can be a perpendicular from B and BPNM can be a rhombus.
